# Convert string to array of elements with different length using regex

Tags: regex, arrays, string

I have a string like  `8305473100342301010102BE7552773845527738451ACAF3D6C8743EC3 0000659A0000000500F107000104FFB50F0C` and I need to parse the whole string to array of elements, but each element may have different size or length. My desired out put may like as follows,

```
Array[0]=83;
Array[1]=05; 
Array[2]=4731003423; 
Array[3]=01; 
Array[4]=01; 
Array[5]=01; 
Array[6]=02; 
Array[7]=BE75; 
Array[8]=52773845; 
Array[9]=52773845; 
Array[10]=1ACAF3D6; 
Array[11]=C8743EC3; 
Array[12]=0000659A; 
Array[13]=00000005; 
Array[14]=00F1; 
Array[15]=07; 
Array[16]=00; 
Array[17]=0104; 
Array[18]=FFB5; 
Array[19]=0F; 
Array[20]=0C;
```

Comment: I have edited the question,ie the input string may not have white-space

Comment: What rule is apply to split elements?

Comment: the rule is array elements must have length 2,2,10,2,2 etc as shown in the question.

Comment: What kind of rule is this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `\S+` as regular expression.

- `\S` matches a non-space character.
- `X+` matches one of more of `x`

Here's Javascript example:

```
> '83 05 4731003423 01 01 01 02 BE75 52773845 52773845 1ACAF3D6 C8743EC3 0000659A 00000005 00F1 07 00 0104 FFB5 0F 0C'.match(/\S+/g)
["83", "05", "4731003423", "01", "01", "01", "02", "BE75", "52773845", "52773845", "1ACAF3D6", "C8743EC3", "0000659A", "00000005", "00F1", "07", "00", "0104", "FFB5", "0F", "0C"]
> '83 AB 0C'.match(/\S+/g)
["83", "AB", "0C"]

> var dynamic_string = '83' + ' ' + 'AAAAAA' + ' ' + 'BEEF';
> dynamic_string.match(/\S+/g)
["83", "AAAAAA", "BEEF"]
```

**UPDATE**

Using capturing group:

```
> var str = '83 05473100342301010102BE7552773845527738451ACAF3D6C8743EC3 0000659A0000000500F107000104FFB50F0C';
> str = str.replace(/\s+/g, '');
> var arr = str.match(/(.{2})(.{2})(.{8})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{4})(.{8})(.{8})(.{8})(.{8})(.{8})(.{8})(.{4})(.{2})(.{2})(.{4})(.{4})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})/);
"8305473100342301010102BE7552773845527738451ACAF3D6C8743EC3 0000659A0000000500F107000104FFB50F0C"
> arr
["8305473100342301010102BE7552773845527738451ACAF3D6C8743EC3 0000659A0000000500F107000104FFB50", "83", "05", "47310034", "23", "01", "01", "01", "02BE", "75527738", "45527738", "451ACAF3", "D6C8743E", "C3 00006", "59A00000", "0050", "0F", "10", "7000", "104F", "FB", "50", "0C"]
> arr.slice(1)
["83", "05", "47310034", "23", "01", "01", "01", "02BE", "75527738", "45527738", "451ACAF3", "D6C8743E", "C3 00006", "59A00000", "0050", "0F", "10", "7000", "104F", "FB", "50", "0C"]
```

BTW, regular expression seems not to be the best tool for this task.

For example, in Python you can do the same thing without regular expression:

```
>>> import struct
>>> s = '83 05473100342301010102BE7552773845527738451ACAF3D6C8743EC3 0000659A0000000500F107000104FFB50F0C'
>>> struct.unpack('2s2s8s2s2s2s2s4s8s8s8s8s8s8s4s2s2s4s4s2s2s2s2s', s)
('83', ' 0', '54731003', '42', '30', '10', '10', '102B', 'E7552773', '84552773', '8451ACAF', '3D6C8743', 'EC3 0000', '659A0000', '0005', '00', 'F1', '0700', '0104', 'FF', 'B5', '0F', '0C')
```

Comment: hi @falsetru the input data may be dynamic.

Comment: @SujathanR, It doesn't matter. You can give any string literal / variable instead of `'83 05 .... 0C'`.

Comment: data may be with different length,and need to convert the input string to array with elements having length 2,2,10,2,2,2,etc

Answer (score 0):

Another way in Javascript, sans regex, would be to use Javascript `split`:

```
"83 05 4731003423 01 01 01 02 BE75 52773845 52773845 1ACAF3D6 C8743EC3 0000659A 00000005 00F1 07 00 0104 FFB5 0F 0C".split(" ");
// returns ["83", "05", "4731003423", "01", "01", "01", "02", "BE75", "52773845", "52773845", "1ACAF3D6", "C8743EC3", "0000659A", "00000005", "00F1", "07", "00", "0104", "FFB5", "0F", "0C"]
```

Answer (score 0):

`string.split(' ');` will give you that exact array